# How to know who created the room?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am trying that when entering a room, only the person who created it obtains permission to change some settings, But I don't know how to get the person who created the room, what can I do?.

I am using photon 2

Comment: What do you mean by "a room"? Do you mean a space inside the game? Or do you mean a chatroom?

Comment: Well, you obviously need to safe the owner/creator of the room when someone creates one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Room has a property named [MasterClientId](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_room.html#a7be9649bcc51a115486ee19e4d76383b), that is the one you are looking for.